# Can solr produce highlight position info for Adobe XML highlighting spec?

Tags: solr

There is a PDF highlighting spec from Adobe that allows one to provide an XML file describing highlight locations to a PDF viewer API. Can Solr produce the highlighting info necessary to produce such a file? Mandatory info would be: page, position, and length. If the answer is yes, any tips on configuring the Solr highlighting component?

Sample XML higlighting file:

```
<XML>
<Body units='characters' color='#ff00ff' mode='active' version='2'>
<Highlight>
    <loc pg='0' pos='0' len='6' />
    <loc pg='2' pos='1' len='10' />
</Highlight>
</Body>
</XML>
```

Comment: Sorry, but no.  Of course, it's open-source and you could hack it to do it, but this wouldn't be easy.  The most likely route to take would be storing the additional offset information needed into Lucene term "payloads".  But getting access to payloads from a typical search is tricky, last I checked, because I recall one needed to use SpanQueries, not the more typical query subclasses.  In summary, possible but hard.

Comment: Btw David, by sheer coincidence, I bought a copy of Apache Solr 3 Enterprise Search Server the day I asked this question. Just realized who you are. Looking forward to reading it. :)